# Codeigniter 4 composer update PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function run() on int in index.php

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

I just updated my Codeigniter 4 site from 4.1 to 4.2 using composer and am now getting the following server error in the Apache error log:

```
PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function run() on int in /var/www/vhosts/site/public/index.php
```

I'm thinking a file has been changed or CI 4.2 requires a missing PHP lib, but I've looked at the .env, /public/index.php and /app/config/App.php file and they haven't changed.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/installation/upgrade_420.html#index-php-and-spark -- make sure you're using the newer index file

Comment: Upgrading from 4.1 to 4.2 wasn't a single version, you jumped ahead a total of ten point releases by doing that. Did you read the change logs for Breaking changes?  https://codeigniter4.github.io/CodeIgniter4/changelogs/index.html

Comment: *I just updated my Codeigniter 4 site from 4.1 to 4.2 using composer ...*. What do you mean by that statement? Did you make any file changes prior to the update (I.e in the file `composer.json`)? Lastly, did you run any composer **specific** command(s) to allow for the stated *update*? Please provide more reproducible information.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Codeigniter v4.2.0 changes**

`index.php` and `spark` files have significant changes in v4.2.0.
To upgrade, you must merge the new versions.

**If** you are using the standard CI4 index.php (you've not modified it):

```
cd <root-dir-of-CI-project>
cp vendor/codeigniter4/framework/public/index.php public/index.php
```

And similarly for standard CI4 `spark` (you've not modified it):

```
cd <root-dir-of-CI-project>
cp vendor/codeigniter4/framework/spark .
```

**ELSE** merge the new versions of `index.php` and `spark` with your current versions.

https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/installation/upgrade_420.html#index-php-and-spark

Comment: Worked for me - thanks man - running CI on Docker!

Answer (score 3):

You should change your index.php like this:

https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/develop/public/index.php

Comment: Please add supporting details to your answer to improve it.

Answer (score 1):

```bash
composer update
cp vendor/codeigniter4/framework/public/index.php public/index.php
cp vendor/codeigniter4/framework/spark
```

https://codeigniter4.github.io/CodeIgniter4/installation/upgrade_420.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded from CI Version: 4.1 to 4.2

At first I used the command:

composer update

Which updated my CI framework and files, but not the Spark and Index file.

But the command below fixed the Spark and Index. I have also attached the CI documentation link below:

composer update --prefer-source

https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/installation/installing_composer.html#adding-codeigniter4-upgrading